# How to update values in database using an update image button in custom list adapter?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

This is my custom list adapter. I want to update the values in table using the update ImageButton in the list. On clicking it, the old values should be shown in a new activity and then the edited value must be stored in the database. However, I am unable to pass an intent inside the onClick() method.

Please suggest me a solution

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter 
     { 
      private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); 
      private Context context; 
      OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectedListener;
      public int pos;
      String pass,pass2,edit,epass;


public CustomListAdapter(List list, Context context) { 
    this.list = (ArrayList<String>) list; 
    this.context = context; 
} 


@Override
public int getCount() { 
    return list.size(); 
} 

@Override
public Object getItem(int pos) {
    //pass2 = list.toString();
    return list.get(pos); 
} 

//@Override
//public Long getItemId(int pos) { 
//    
//    //just return 0 if your list items do not have an Id variable.
//} 

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_custom_list, null);
    } 

    //Handle TextView and display string from your list
    final TextView listItemText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_string); 
    listItemText.setText(list.get(position)); 






    //Handle buttons and add onClickListeners
    ImageButton deleteBtn = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);
    ImageButton editBtn = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.edit_btn);
    //Button addBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.add_btn);

    deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            //do something
            list.remove(position);
            pass = listItemText.getText().toString();

            notifyDataSetChanged();
            pass2 = pass.substring(0,pass.indexOf(' '));
            System.out.println(pass2);
            Moneydb.delete(pass2);
        }
    }); 
    editBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            edit=listItemText.getText().toString();
            epass = listItemText.getText().toString();
            edit = epass.substring(0,epass.indexOf(' '));
            Moneydb.edit(edit);

        }
    });


    return view; 
}

protected Context getContext() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //return list.get(position).getId();
    return 0;
}


public void clear() {
    //CustomListAdapter collection = null;
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    list.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: why do you want to pass an intent? to start another activity?

Comment: Then how will i edit the values from database ?

Comment: I want to pass an intent to fetch the database values and show it in the new Activity.If you have any other solutions tell me

Comment: What is happening now? And you don't need Intent to retrieve values from Database. Only to navigate to next activity and pass values you need intent.

Comment: @Farrokh is right. If there no compulsion on the edit and image button then try using context menus they are meant for these features. But still if you want to go with the current layout, pass your context object to your adapters constructor and you can use this to go to your next Activity via Intents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to assign and `ContextMenu` to your list view with two `MenuItem`, `Edit` and `Delete` and write associated code outside of adapter

or you can start Activity by :

```
Intent new_intent = new Intent(v.getRootView().getContext(),edit_activity.class);
new_intent.putExtra("Key","Value");
v.getRootView().getContext().startActivity(new_intent);
```

i think the first method is best ;)

Comment: But i need three fields to enter. So does that mean ill have to create all that in layout in ContextMenu ?

Comment: create a menu with two menuitem `Edit` and `Delete`, assign it to your listview and finally in `onContextItemSelected` do anything you want or use the second method...

Comment: I don't want to use ContextMenu as the custom list view looks good and easy to use.Can you tell me more options.

Comment: then you should to use second method, `v.getRootView().getContext()` described in my answer